# Entity framework throwing error 3021 on a 1 to 1 association

Tags: entity-framework

I have created an association between two entities in EF 5.
When I try to build the dll I get an error 3021 on these lines of the EDMX file.

```
<AssociationSetMapping Name="NameAddress1" TypeName="MyModel.NameAddress1" StoreEntitySet="Name">
        <EndProperty Name="Address">
          <ScalarProperty Name="ID" ColumnName="ID" />
        </EndProperty>
        <EndProperty Name="Name">
          <ScalarProperty Name="ID" ColumnName="ID" />
        </EndProperty>
      </AssociationSetMapping>
```

The exact error is

```
Error 3021: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line xxxx:Each of the following
 columns in table Name is mapped to multiple conceptual side properties:
Name.ID is mapped to <NameAddress1.Address.ID, NameAddress1.Name.ID>
```

This is a one to one association. The underlying data is a table and a view. There is no FK on the SQL side. This is strictly a read-only app.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Added a referential constraint and all works now.

Comment: You have to wait at least one day before you can mark your own answer